# How to send a HTTP response back to shopify for the payment session creation to be successful?

Tags: php, shopify

Am creating a payment app on Shopify but am stuck.. any assistance will be appreciated.

> Shopify must receive an HTTP 2xx response with a redirect url for the payment session creation to be successful.
> How do you send such when no endpoint is provided or probably am missing something but I have done all the configuration correctly. Am stuck at ***Your payment can’t be processed for technical reasons*** - above must be the cause just I don't know how to go about it. The redirect url is required to redirect customer back to partner's payment page for payment processing.

Relevant documentation: https://shopify.dev/apps/payments/processing-a-payment#http-response-example

Answer (score 0):

Here is the endpoint with the redirect URL and status code.

POST https://{shop_domain}/payments_apps/api/{api_version}/graphql.json

```
mutation PaymentSessionResolve($id: ID!, $authorizationExpiresAt: DateTime) {
  paymentSessionResolve(id: $id, authorizationExpiresAt: $authorizationExpiresAt) {
    paymentSession {
      id
      status {
        code
      }
      nextAction {
        action
        context {
          ... on PaymentSessionActionsRedirect {
            redirectUrl
          }
        }
      }
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```